# How to write an optimized SQL query?

Tags: sql

How to write an optimized SQL query to get results in table 1 which are not in table 2 and table 3, similarly in table 2 which are not in table 1 and table 3  and for in table 3 which are not in table 1 and table 2

I'm trying to improve performance of my query that I'm Currently working on

```
TABLE A 
LEFT JOIN B
LEFT JOIN C 
WHERE B is NULL and C is NULL

UNION  

TABLE B 
LEFT JOIN A
LEFT JOIN C 
WHERE A is NULL and C is NULL

UNION  

TABLE C 
LEFT JOIN A
LEFT JOIN B 
WHERE A is NULL and B is NULL
```

Is there any way where we can avoid reading the table 3 times?

Comment: Are you actually using both MySQL and SQL-Server? If not please only tag the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: Please also put your join conditions in - hard to answer if the table structure isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full outer join.

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from a full outer join b on
        a.A_keys = b.B_keys
    full outer join c on
        a.A_keys = c.C_keys AND
        b.B_keys = c.C_keys
```

As others have indicated because you did not supply sample data or join condition it is impossible to guess whether the second join (to c) requires conditions to both A and B or just A or just B. So you will need to work that bit out for your self.

For reference, a FULL OUTER JOIN is like doing a LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOIN in one go. That is, it will return:

- all records that match on both sides of the join (the INNER join), plus
- all records that are in the LEFT table but not in the right (the LEFT outer join). Right table records will be NULL
- all records that are in the RIGHT table but not in the left (the RIGHT outer join). Left table records will be NULL

I will leave it to you to add the "NULL filters" to get the records you are interested in.

Comment: @Sai, if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and upvote it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

So, unique from A, unique from B, unique from C ?  As there are no other rows from other tables, I think you just want

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
UNION 
SELECT * FROM C
```

Comment: The OP wants to know which records are in A but not B or C, similarly in B but not A nor C. This query will simply combine all the records in A, B and C, dedupe and return the complete set. It won't show the "missing" records.

Comment: @GMc: Yes that is what this does.  Assuming there are 3 identical tables, if you work it through it washes out to this.  All those unique to A plus all those unique to B plus all those unique to C.  That's a UNION of them all.  I fully realise that  if that is not the requirement my approach is not correct.  If it's 3 different results then yes, it's a different problem.

Comment: @LotzInSpace That is an interesting interpretation. The original question is a little unclear. I guess in the sample query the OP supplied, the OP seems to trying to exclude records common to the three tables - via the IS NULL tests. Hopefully the OP will clarify further the intention. Sai can you clarify your expected result along with some sample inputs?